# Identifying an hovered element with jquery without using id's?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way with jQuery to know which div you have just rolled out of without using id's?

Basically I have something like the following scenario:

If a user hovers over a div it is turned red.
If a user hovers over another div, all divs are turned white (basically resetting everything), and the currently hovered over div turns red. 
However, if a user rolls over a div to turn it red, and out and back into the same one I don't want it to go back white and then to red.

Comment: Can you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) it? Will make it much easier to help.

Comment: Its not really classes I want to add an remove. Maybe I gave a bad example. Essentially a box contains three boxes with can be shown or hidden. I want to reset all boxes to their original state when the mouse enters a box that isn't the one it left. if it re-enters the box it left it should remain in the same state.

Comment: Like @ShadowWizard says, code it in jsfiddle

Comment: Actually I think adding a class, even if its not doing anything will work. I just wondered if jQuery knew which elements had just been hovered out of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another solution: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ep39L/1/

```
var last;

$('div').mouseenter(function(e) {
    var elm = $(e.target);
    if (last != elm) {
        $('div').css('background', 'white');
        elm.css('background', 'red');
    }
    last=elm;
    $('div').eq(2).html(last.index()+1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a class when you mouseover and then check if that class exists when mouseover again. If it doesnt then clear the class from all divs. If you don't want to use classes you can use [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and [.removeData](http://api.jquery.com/removeData/):

```
$('div').on('mouseover', function() {       
    if (!$(this).hasClass('red')) {
       $('div').removeClass('red');
    }
    $(this).addClass('red'); 
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/29E4t/)

Answer (score 0):

When hovered, give it a temporary class:

```
$(this).addClass();
```

Then when you're ready to remove it use:

```
$(this).removeClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use not:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("div span").click(function(){
  $(this).closest("div").find("span").not(this).css("background", "#fff");
  $(this).css("background", "#f00");
});
```